# Best raisins to make raisin wine for kiddush?

Tags: product-recommendation, grapes-wine, kiddush

Raisin wine.

[SO O Ch 272 (6)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.272.6?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) quotes the Tur to say

> יין צמוקים מקדשים עליו (והוא שיש בהן לחלוחית קצת בלא שרייה) (טור):
>
> Kiddush may be recited over raisin wine (provided some moisture can be
> squeezed from them before they are steeped in water) (Tur).

The raisins that I see do not yield moisture on squeezing.

What are the best raisins to use for making raisin wine over which to make kiddush?

Comment: I think not the seedless ones.

Comment: Sultanas are not recommended because they are often dipped in oil, which will tend to float on the surface of the wine and impart undesirable flavors.